# Class binding in Vue does not show correctly

Tags: vue.js

I starting with Vue and have a div that does not behave like it should. I would appreciate if someone could explain it :

```
<div id="static" v-bind:class="classObject"><p>tralala</p></div>
```

The vue script looks like this:

```
var watchExampleVM = new Vue({
  el: '#static',
  data: {
      classObject: {
        active: true,
        'text-danger': true
    }
  }
  
})
```

My expectation is that tralala would be highlighted in red but it is not. The resulting html code is for my div class="active text-danger".

Comment: How are the css rules defined?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I do not have any css rules for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the CSS rules to the used classes like :

```js
var watchExampleVM = new Vue({
  el: '#static',
  data: {
    classObject: {
      active: true,
      'text-danger': true
    }
  }

})
```

```css
.text-danger {
  color: red
}

.active {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="static" v-bind:class="classObject">
  <p>tralala</p>
</div>
```